# How to create a csv. from a table that came from a merge routine (R)? Somehow the table is not saved and I can't convert it into a dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio

```
library(reshape2)
Customer<- c("Susan","Louis", "Frank","Susan")
Seller<- c("Ivan", "Donald","Chris","Ivan")
Service<-c("COU","CAR", "FCL","CAR")
Billingmean<- c(100,200,300,400)
WrsHoldSum<-c(0,0,0,0)
Group<- c("n1","n2"," "," ")
B1<- c(0,2,2,1) 
B2<-c(9,8,7,6)
B3<- c(5,4,3,2)
```

> This dataframe includes information such as Billing mean of last years
>   sales, Seller, Type of service

```
df<- data.frame(Customer, Seller,Service, Billingmean,WrsHoldSum, Group,B1,B2,B3)
```

> This section uses dcast to change the configuration of the dframe so I can use this file later in Word to fill some Directories in the "Mail Merge" mode

```
sub1<- dcast(data= df, formula= Customer+Group+Seller+WrsHoldSum~Service,fun.aggregate= sum,value.var= "Billingmean")
sub2<- dcast(data= df, formula= Customer+Group+Seller+WrsHoldSum~Service,fun.aggregate= sum,value.var= "B1") 
sub3<- dcast(data= df, formula= Customer+Group+Seller+WrsHoldSum~Service,fun.aggregate= sum,value.var= "B2")
sub4<- dcast(data= df, formula= Customer+Group+Seller+WrsHoldSum~Service,fun.aggregate= sum,value.var= "B3")
```

> Here I add new columns to add the information in a table, however is not nested on the environment to call it on the write.csv() function.

```
tNames <- grep(x = ls(), pattern = "^sub", value = T)

lapply(seq_along(tNames), function(x){
  tSym <- as.name(tNames[[x]])

  d1 <- copy(eval(tSym))

  cols <- grep(x = names(d1), pattern = "^CAR|^COU|^FCL", value = T)

  setnames(d1, old = cols, new = paste0(cols, " B", x))

  return(d1)

}) %>% Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = c("Customer","Group","Seller","WrsHoldSum")), .)
```

> here I don't know if there's another way to merge the new columns of Billing1 (B1), Billing 2 (B2), Billing 3(B3)..
>
> This is the expected output

```
Customer Group Seller WrsHoldSum CAR B1 COU B1 FCL B1 CAR B2 COU B2 FCL B2 CAR B3 COU B3 FCL B3 CAR B4 COU B4 FCL B4
1    Frank        Chris          0      0      0    300      0      0      2      0      0      7      0      0      3
2    Louis    n2 Donald          0    200      0      0      2      0      0      8      0      0      4      0      0
3    Susan         Ivan          0    400      0      0      1      0      0      6      0      0      2      0      0
4    Susan    n1   Ivan          0      0    100      0      0      0      0      0      9      0      0      5      0
```

Comment: can you show the expected output? The output is a data.frame, you may need to assign it to an object i.e. `res <- lapply(seq_len....` and then use `write.csv(res, "yourfile.csv", quote= FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: I can `write.csv(res, "test.csv")`. No errors.

Comment: yeah that was the problem, thank you